# 'exit when not found;' does not work and how to bypass that using smth like 'exit when cursor==''

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am using a cursor, fetching one column 'email1' table 'pepe_emails' of 10 items. Inside the loop I try to append the content fetched in an array.

There is a previous error that the one I mention in this post. By the way, Here the problem is the fetch loop, that becomes in an infinite loop, when using *'exit when not found;'*.
I tried to bypass the *'exit when not found'*. But I did not get something similar as this idea: 'exit when cursor_emails == '';'. This is not right in postgresql but something like right written would work. at the output showed, here should break:

```
NOTICE:  Loop 10
NOTICE:  Value: ()
```

Here is my current and failed code:

```
do $$
declare
    cursor_emails cursor for
        select pepe_emails.email1
        from pepe_emails;

    arr_emails varchar[];
    table_record record;
    i integer := 0;

    begin
        raise notice 'Hola 1';
        open cursor_emails;
        loop
        raise notice 'Loop %', i;
        i = i + 1;
            fetch cursor_emails into table_record;
            raise notice 'Value: %', table_record;
            perform array_append (arr_emails, table_record::varchar);
            raise notice 'Value: %', arr_emails[-1];
        exit when not found;
        end loop;

    close cursor_emails;

    end;
$$;
```

And this is the output of this code:

```
NOTICE:  Hola 1
NOTICE:  Loop 0
NOTICE:  Value: (us_1.gmail.com)
NOTICE:  Value: <NULL>
NOTICE:  Loop 1
NOTICE:  Value: (us_2.gmail.com)
NOTICE:  Value: <NULL>
NOTICE:  Loop 2
NOTICE:  Value: (us_3.gmail.com)
NOTICE:  Value: <NULL>
NOTICE:  Loop 3
...
NOTICE:  Value: (us_9.gmail.com)
NOTICE:  Value: <NULL>
NOTICE:  Loop 9
NOTICE:  Value: (us_10.gmail.com)
NOTICE:  Value: <NULL>
NOTICE:  Loop 10
NOTICE:  Value: ()
NOTICE:  Value: <NULL>
NOTICE:  Loop 11
NOTICE:  Value: ()
NOTICE:  Value: <NULL>
```

Thanx in advance

Answer (score 1):

[The documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-DIAGNOSTICS) says:

> `FOUND` starts out false within each PL/pgSQL function call. It is set by each of the following types of statements:
>
> [...]
>
> - A `PERFORM` statement sets `FOUND` true if it produces (and discards) one or more rows, false if no row is produced.
>
> [...]
>
> - A `FETCH` statement sets `FOUND` true if it returns a row, false if no row is returned.

So in order to get your desired result, you will have to move the test right behind the `FETCH`, otherwise the value is changed by the `PERFORM`.